# How much data storage will be lost converting a 4 GB Compact Flash from FAT32 to FAT16?

Tags: filesystems, storage, fat32, fat16

i would need to know how to calculate the space still available after formatting if had been lost. 
I will use a device for collecting physiological data that requires FAT16, on the other hand i would need 4 GB for the duration of the recordings. So i am trying to find a solution.

Comment: FAT16 can't do 4GB partitions, let alone 4GB files. So, I guess the answer would be "you will lose 2GB"… being the maximum partition size.

Comment: @tetsujin I thought 4gb partitions were the limit, at least in Windows from XP and above?

Comment: I just wouldn't trust anything that's limited to FAT16 to be good for FAT16B, it just hopes for too much. FAT32 support would be easier to have implemented. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Final_FAT16

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the 2GB volume size limit is based on a cluster size of 32KB. If you manage to format it with a cluster size of 64KB, you should be able to utilize the 4GB CF fully. However, whether it will be compatible with your device is in doubt.